# Fundamentally, how different is an AJAX call from a form submission in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

So I've been converting some code from form submission to ajax calls, since form submission validation requires a postback and server calculations that take a long time to do and provide a bad UX, where instead I can validate some of it with Javascript and the rest with an ajax call in the background while the user does other things.

My question is, if I were to validate, say, a password, using an ajax call instead of a form submission in ASP.NET, is there a security risk or general major difference in using ajax instead of a form? Is it better to use one or the other?

As I understand it, if it's over HTTPS, then there isn't a security risk, but I feel like that could be wrong.

Edit: This is for Webforms, not MVC.

Comment: An AJAX call is just another type of HTTP request, so in that sense there's no massive difference.  You should use HTTPS whether it's AJAX or not. And whichever design you use, you should never ever rely on JavaScript alone to do your validation. It's fine to enhance the UX by doing client-side validation (and again this can be done with a postback, not just AJAX), but this can be bypassed by malicious users quite easily, so you must _always_ do server-side validation as well, no matter how the request occurs.

Comment: In general, AJAX often gives you a way to provide a smoother UX, and that's a good reason to use it. If you're sending and receiving the same data as you did via postback (even if maybe it's in JSON format now rather than form-data in and HTML out), and carrying out the same validations of the input data on the server, then it shouldn't really increase your security risk. It can also, as you say, improve performance by not having to do calculations to re-load other parts of the page which have not really changed due to the user's last action.

Comment: In WebForms, the postback mechanism does include some built-in security in the framework to try and mitigate against spoofing of the request, CSRF and that kind of thing. You can easily re-create CSRF protection in particular when using AJAX, but you just have to add and validate the tokens yourself (there might be a library out there, I don't know - in MVC it's built-in no matter what the type of request) so it needn't be a loss necessarily.

Comment: It is Webforms. I am doing the same validations server-side of course, but for the average, non-malicious user, it's nice to have the immediate feedback of "your username is too short" instead of waiting for the server to postback and eventually tell you so. But if as you said I'm doing all the same validations on the server-side, and using HTTPS, that there's no security risk, then I will continue doing it this way. Thanks! :)

Comment: "it's nice to have the immediate feedback of "your username is too short" instead of waiting for the server to postback" ...as I mentioned you can do that without having to switch to AJAX. If you're already using ValidationControls it should be provided out of the box (I forget if there's a config switch to enable it, it's a few years since I switched form WebForms to MVC (and never looked back, it's much easier to work with!)).

Comment: It was just an example, but yeah I know, don't worry. A better example is checking if a username exists. You can either do that by waiting on a postback, or do an AJAX call while the user fills in other fields, and get back if it exists or not without needing to submit. That's a better example why I wanted to switch to this method. :)

Comment: yes that's a very good use case for AJAX, I agree. It's like a form of remote validation, if you like - i.e. you do what is essentially a client-side validation pattern, except that it calls out to the server to actually do the test and then return the result for JS to display the outcome. Of course if you then separately submit a completed form containing a field populated with that ajax-validated username, you still have to validate it again (since it could be tampered with after the ajax ran) on the server during the main form submission.